The push notification does not link to the screen
When I launch the application via Expo Go and test the notification, the target screen opens after clicking on it. However, when I build the APK and run it on a physical device, nothing happens when I click on the received notification.
When I check the log through Android Studio / DEBUG, I get the following:
2024-08-08 23:44:01.315 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=33.51ms min=12.44ms max=72.02ms count=27
2024-08-08 23:44:01.836 24487-24491 my.app.package.name     I  NativeAlloc concurrent mark compact GC freed 7901KB AllocSpace bytes, 30(936KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 11MB/23MB, paused 10.083ms,2.385ms total 299.526ms
2024-08-08 23:44:03.446 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=97.43ms min=3.60ms max=1518.18ms count=21
2024-08-08 23:44:04.481 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=15.67ms min=2.44ms max=38.54ms count=45
2024-08-08 23:44:05.517 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=53.96ms min=4.06ms max=572.25ms count=18
2024-08-08 23:44:05.578 24487-24649 notifications           my.app.package.name  E  Couldn't get channel for the notifications - trigger is 'null'. Fallback to 'expo_notifications_fallback_notification_channel' channel
2024-08-08 23:44:06.933 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=109.35ms min=2.31ms max=1171.37ms count=12
2024-08-08 23:44:08.011 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=31.38ms min=3.04ms max=228.85ms count=29
2024-08-08 23:44:09.094 24487-24487 VRI[MainActivity]       my.app.package.name  D  visibilityChanged oldVisibility=true newVisibility=false
2024-08-08 23:44:09.227 24487-24559 ReactNativeJNI          my.app.package.name  I  Memory warning (pressure level: TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) received by JS VM, ignoring because it's non-severe
2024-08-08 23:44:11.632 24487-24487 ReactNativeJS           my.app.package.name  D  [native] ExpoNotificationLifecycleListener contains an unmarshaled notification response. Skipping.
2024-08-08 23:44:11.650 24487-24559 ReactNativeJS           my.app.package.name  W  Event data is missing in the notification payload.
2024-08-08 23:44:11.650 24487-24559 ReactNativeJS           my.app.package.name  W  Event data is missing in the notification payload.
2024-08-08 23:44:13.298 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=71.31ms min=13.70ms max=216.31ms count=17
2024-08-08 23:44:16.131 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=89.93ms min=3.68ms max=2012.98ms count=30
2024-08-08 23:44:17.139 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=16.40ms min=3.34ms max=37.08ms count=45
2024-08-08 23:44:19.622 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=139.47ms min=3.89ms max=2030.02ms count=17
2024-08-08 23:44:20.639 24487-24506 EGL_emulation           my.app.package.name  D  app_time_stats: avg=26.14ms min=6.18ms max=69.69ms count=30

What I get when I do the same process in the Expo Go environment locally:
and requesting notification permissions...
 LOG  Resources loaded, navigation is ready.
 LOG  ExponentPushToken[anamAFPyKU4GsU7YpbF20f]
 LOG  Scheduling notifications for event: {"field1": "0.00", "field2": "2024-08-08", "field3": "XX.XXXXXX", "field4": "some_value", "field5": "XX.XXXXX", "field6": "another_value", "field7": "yet_another_value", "field8": "123123123", "field9": "20:00:00", "field10": "12:00:00", "field11": "2", "field12": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg"}
 LOG  Scheduling immediate notification: {"attachments": [{"url": "https://example.com/admin/public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg"}], "body": "Notification message.", "data": {"event": {"field1": "0.00", "field2": "2024-08-08", "field3": "XX.XXXXX", "field4": "some_value", "field5": "XX.XXXXX", "field6": "another_value", "field7": "yet_another_value", "field8": "123123123", "field9": "20:00:00", "field10": "12:00:00", "active": undefined, "field11": "2", "id": "2", "image": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1", "imagePath": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1", "field12": XX.XXXXX, "field13": "some_value", "field14": XX.XXXXX, "field15": "another_value", "field16": "123123123", "field17": "0.00", "field18": "12:00:00 - 20:00:00"}}, "sound": "default", "title": "Notification title header"}       
 LOG  Notification response: {
  "notification": {
    "request": {
      "trigger": null,
      "content": {
        "title": "Header title",
        "badge": null,
        "autoDismiss": true,
        "data": {
          "event": {
            "field1": "XX.XXXXX",
            "field2": "2",
            "field3": "some_value",
            "field4": "0.00",
            "field5": "0.00",
            "field6": "123123123",
            "field7": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg",
            "field8": "2024-08-08",
            "field9": "another_value",
            "field10": "2024-08-08",
            "field11": "12:00:00 - 20:00:00",
            "field12": XX.XXXXX,
            "field13": "yet_another_value",
            "field14": "another_value",
            "id": "2",
            "field15": "20:00:00",
            "field16": "123123123",
            "field17": "some_value",
            "field18": "XX.XXXXX",
            "field19": "12:00:00",
            "field20": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg",
            "field21": XX.XXXXX,
            "field22": "another_value"
          }
        },
        "body": "Notification message",       
        "sound": "custom",
        "sticky": false,
        "subtitle": null
      },
      "identifier": "285406aa-4d79-4889-85c7-8f162eed835e"
    },
    "date": 1723155191850
  },
  "actionIdentifier": "expo.modules.notifications.actions.DEFAULT"
}
 LOG  Notification response: {
  "notification": {
    "request": {
      "trigger": null,
      "content": {
        "title": "example",
        "badge": null,
        "autoDismiss": true,
        "data": {
          "event": {
            "field1": "XX.XXXXX",
            "field2": "2",
            "field3": "some_value",
            "field4": "0.00",
            "field5": "0.00",
            "field6": "123123123",
            "field7": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg",
            "field8": "2024-08-08",
            "field9": "another_value",
            "field10": "2024-08-08",
            "field11": "12:01:00 - 20:00:00",
            "field12": XX.XXXXX,
            "field13": "yet_another_value",
            "field14": "another_value",
            "id": "2",
            "field15": "20:00:00",
            "field16": "123123123",
            "field17": "some_value",
            "field18": "XX.XXXXX",
            "field19": "12:01:00",
            "field20": "../public/template/images/placeholder/1.jpg",
            "field21": XX.XXXXX,
            "field22": "another_value"
          }
        },
        "body": "Notification message",       
        "sound": "custom",
        "sticky": false,
        "subtitle": null
      },
      "identifier": "285406aa-4d79-4889-85c7-8f162eed835e"
    },
    "date": 1723155191850
  },
  "actionIdentifier": "expo.modules.notifications.actions.DEFAULT"
}
 LOG  Notification response received: {"actionIdentifier": "expo.modules.notifications.actions.DEFAULT", "notification": {"date": 1723155191850, "request": {"content": [Object], "identifier": "285406aa-4d79-4889-85c7-8f162eed835e", "trigger": null}}}

And when I launch the application through Expo Go and click on the notification, it opens the screen I need, while nothing opens in production.
App.js:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Navigation from './Components/StackNavigation';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { useNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { Platform, Alert } from 'react-native';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  console.log = () => {};
}

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
  let token;
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;
  if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    finalStatus = status;
  }
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    Alert.alert("Permissions required", "You need to enable notifications permissions.");
    return;
  }

  token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
  console.log(token);

  return token;
};

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const isNavigationReady = useRef(false);
  const pendingNotificationResponse = useRef(null);

  const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');

  const handleNotificationResponse = useCallback((response) => {
    console.log('Notification response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    const event = response.notification.request.content.data?.event;
    if (event) {
      if (isNavigationReady.current) {
        navigationRef.current?.navigate('Event Details', { event });
      } else {
        pendingNotificationResponse.current = response;
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('Event data is missing in the notification payload.');
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

    const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(handleNotificationResponse);
    return () => subscription.remove();
  }, [handleNotificationResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadResourcesAndDataAsync() {
      try {
        console.log('Loading fonts and requesting notification permissions...');
        await Font.loadAsync({
          // Load fonts
        });

        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need notification permissions to make this work!');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        console.log('Resources loaded, navigation is ready.');
        setFontsLoaded(true);
        SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        isNavigationReady.current = true;

        if (pendingNotificationResponse.current) {
          handleNotificationResponse(pendingNotificationResponse.current);
          pendingNotificationResponse.current = null;
        }
      }
    }

    loadResourcesAndDataAsync();
  }, [handleNotificationResponse]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Navigation
      ref={navigationRef}
      linking={{
        prefixes: [prefix],
        config: {
          screens: {
            EventDetails: 'Event Details',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}

A screen that contains the context of notifications, etc...
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

// Set up the notification handler
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});

// Function to request notification permissions
const requestNotificationPermissions = async () => {
  const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    Alert.alert("Permissions required", "You need to enable notifications permissions.");
  }
};

// Function to clean image URLs
const cleanUrl = (url) => {
  const urlParts = url.split('/public/template/images/').pop();
  return `${config.BASE_URL}project-login/public/template/images/${urlParts}`;
};

// Function to schedule notifications for events
const scheduleNotifications = async (events) => {
  const now = moment();

  for (const event of events) {
    const eventStartDate = moment(event.date).set({
      hour: parseInt(event.startTime.split(':')[0]),
      minute: parseInt(event.startTime.split(':')[1]),
    });

    const oneDayBeforeEvent = eventStartDate.clone().subtract(1, 'days');
    const oneHourBeforeEvent = eventStartDate.clone().subtract(1, 'hours');

    console.log('Scheduling notifications for event:', event);

    if (oneDayBeforeEvent.isAfter(now)) {
      const notificationContent24h = {
        title: event.name,
        body: `Reminder: "${event.name}" starts in 24 hours at ${moment(event.startTime, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')}!`,
        data: { event },
        sound: 'default',
        attachments: [{
          url: cleanUrl(event.imagePath)
        }],
      };
      console.log('Notification content 24h:', notificationContent24h);
      await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: notificationContent24h,
        trigger: {
          date: oneDayBeforeEvent.toDate(),
        },
      });
    }

    if (oneHourBeforeEvent.isAfter(now)) {
      const notificationContent1h = {
        title: event.name,
        body: `Reminder: "${event.name}" starts in 1 hour at ${moment(event.startTime, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')}!`,
        data: { event },
        sound: 'default',
        attachments: [{
          url: cleanUrl(event.imagePath)
        }],
      };
      console.log('Notification content 1h:', notificationContent1h);
      await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: notificationContent1h,
        trigger: {
          date: oneHourBeforeEvent.toDate(),
        },
      });
    }
  }
};

// Effect to handle incoming notification responses
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
    console.log('Notification response received:', response);
    if (response.notification.request.content.data && response.notification.request.content.data.event) {
      const { event } = response.notification.request.content.data;
      navigation.navigate('Event Details', { event });
    } else {
      console.warn('Event data is missing in the notification payload.');
    }
  });

  return () => subscription.remove();
}, [navigation]);

// Function to trigger an immediate notification
const handleEventNotification = async () => {
  if (savedEvents.length > 0) {
    const event = savedEvents[Math.floor(Math.random() * savedEvents.length)];
    const eventDate = moment(event.date).format('DD. MMMM YYYY');
    const eventTime = moment(event.startTime, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm');

    const notificationContent = {
      title: "Event Reminder",
      body: `Reminder: "${event.name}" starts at ${eventTime} on ${eventDate}.`,
      data: { 
        event: {
          ...event,
          id: event.event_id,
          name: event.name,
          description: event.description,
          date: event.date,
          active: event.status,
          time: `${event.startTime} - ${event.endTime}`,
          location: event.location,
          latitude: parseFloat(event.latitude), 
          longitude: parseFloat(event.longitude),  
          phone: event.phone,
          image: event.imagePath,
          price: event.ticketPrice
        }
      },
      sound: 'default',
      attachments: [{
        url: cleanUrl(`${config.BASE_URL}project-login/public/template/images/events/${event.imagePath}`)
      }],
    };
    console.log('Scheduling immediate notification:', notificationContent);
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: notificationContent,
      trigger: null,
    });
  } else {
    Alert.alert("No events", "You have no saved events.");
  }
};

// Function to trigger a notification one hour before the event
const handleEventNotificationOneHour = async () => {
  if (savedEvents.length > 0) {
    const event = savedEvents[Math.floor(Math.random() * savedEvents.length)];
    const eventDate = moment(event.date).format('DD. MMMM YYYY');
    const eventTime = moment(event.startTime, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm');

    const notificationContent = {
      title: "Event Reminder",
      body: `Reminder: "${event.name}" starts in 1 hour at ${eventTime} on ${eventDate}.`,
      data: { 
        event: {
          ...event,
          id: event.event_id,
          name: event.name,
          description: event.description,
          date: event.date,
          active: event.status,
          time: `${event.startTime} - ${event.endTime}`,
          location: event.location,
          latitude: parseFloat(event.latitude),
          longitude: parseFloat(event.longitude),
          phone: event.phone,
          image: event.imagePath,
          price: event.ticketPrice
        }
      },
      sound: 'default',
      attachments: [{
        url: cleanUrl(`${config.BASE_URL}project-login/public/template/images/events/${event.imagePath}`)
      }],
    };
    console.log('Scheduling immediate notification (one hour before):', notificationContent);
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: notificationContent,
      trigger: null,
    });
  } else {
    Alert.alert("No events", "You have no saved events.");
  }
};

